# absdiff. Возникло необработанное исключение Microsoft C++: cv::Exception

Tags: c++, исключения, opencv

Пытаюсь вычесть межкадровую разницу. Как только дело доходит до absdiff, возникает необработанное исключение. Но я не понимаю где ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("C:/.../Name1.jpg", 0); //В проекте путь прописан полностью
    cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("C:/.../Name2.jpg", 0);

    cv::Mat difference;

    cv::absdiff(img2, img1, difference);

    cv::imshow("img1", img1);
    cv::imshow("img2", img2);
    cv::imshow("difference", difference);

    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Исключение возникает на первой строчке с `cv::imshow`. Если убрать cv::imshow, всё равно возникает исключение на `cv::waitKey()`.

Comment: Приведите место возникновения исключения со стеком вызовов.

Comment: Место: cv::imshow("img1", img1);
Стек:
KernelBase.dll!00007ffc62d4d759() Нет данных
  vcruntime140.dll!00007ffc47936480() Нет данных
  opencv_world451.dll!cv::error(class cv::Exception const &) C++
  opencv_world451.dll!cv::error(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *,char const *,int) C++

Comment: Продолжение стека: opencv_world451.dll!cv::addWeighted(class cv::_InputArray const &,double,class cv::_InputArray const &,double,double,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int) C++
  opencv_world451.dll!cv::absdiff(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &) C++
> ConsoleApplication1.exe!main() Строка 26 C++
  [Внешний код]

Comment: Это все стоило добавить отредактировав сам вопрос...

Comment: @RamRai Я не знаток винды, но что-то мне подсказывает, что ваши пути неверные. Если вы так не считаете, то объясните пожалуйста в какой все-таки директории находятся изображения. И да, хорошим тоном является: проверять данные на их валидность перед использованием. И это обязательно, если у вас возникают проблемы

Comment: Еще стоит проверить img1 и img2 на одинаковость размеров, типа, числа каналов.

Comment: @AlexAlex спасибо большое, ваш совет помог! Действительно, была проблема в размерах. А можно ещё вопрос, пожалуйста? OpenCV умеет автоматически привести размер второго изображения к первому? Я просто нашла синтаксис изменения именно с пикселями, то есть это всё вручную смотреть и прописывать надо. А вдруг умеет, просто я не нашла как? Я совсем новичок в OpenCV. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Считываете размеры первого изображения. И вызывете функцию resize с этими размерами  для второго изображения.

Comment: @AlexAlex ещё раз благодарю!